# Shell substitution/replace not working as expected with Perl and SED

Tags: regex, perl, shell, sed, substitution

I have a number of strings in the format:

```
Sys!CTP_Live83000_@DRS_named_error_out_1
EServerJTP!CTP_Live56000_@input_error_queue_205
```

I'm trying to remove the "_number" i.e. "_1" and "_205" from the end but I'm having some trouble.

So far I've come up with 2 solutions, neither of which work quite as I'd like

1) Using Perl, this replaces the underscore and the number at the end of the String with whitespace but it also replaces all occurrences of _ within the string too.

```
...|/usr/bin/perl -pi -e 's/[_][0-9]*/ /g'
```

2) Using SED, this keeps the underscores in the string intact, but only deletes(replaces with whitespace) the underscore and first number from the end of the string, in the case of 2 and 3 digit numbers some digits remain:

```
...|sed 's/[_][0-9]/ /'
```

This is on a Solaris 5.10 server.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to remove the `_number` completely or replace it with a whitespace?

Comment: Thank you all for your answers, it's much appreciated. I tried all the SED solutions but I couldn't get any of them to work but the perl solution did work. I'm not sure why the SED solutions didn't work, I have had issues with SED in the past on this server, I have asked the people who manage the server if there is a non-standard verion of SED installed, but they confirmed that it is the default one that comes bundled with Solaris?

Comment: I'm very surprised that my solution didn't work, as it is effectively the same regex as the Perl answer and is fully POSIX compatible (so should work on any version of sed). You can `sed --version` to find out what version you are using.

Comment: @skamazin Well ideally I'd like to replace the "_number" with the same amount of whitespace, however due to the issue with SED not working as expected, I kind of gave up on that idea and went with plan B which was to simply remove it.

Comment: @TomFenech Unfortunately when I try sed --version/-v etc.. I get a message saying "sed: illegal option -v" or "sed: illegal option --version". "man sed" gives the following info: "SunOS 5.10          Last change: 23 Jul 1998  1 User Commands      sed(1)"

Comment: I just took a look at the manpage for the version of sed that comes with your version of SunOS. I think the problem with my suggestion might have been the `[:digit:]` character class. I have added another suggestion to my answer, I'd be curious to find out if it works!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `[0-9]*` allows for *zero or more* digits thereby allowing your regex to match a bare underscore `_`.

To make sure there is at least one digit you can use `+` instead of `*`.

Als the `/g` option is inappropriate here because you only want to substitute one occurrence of the pattern, and the `-i` perl option is irrelevant if you are always piping to this command, so that gives

```
perl -pe 's/_[0-9]+/ /'
```

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that while the `-i` will not have any negative effects, it may as well be removed if the input is on STDIN (as it appears to be in the question).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your input is in `file`:

```
sed -e 's/_[[:digit:]]\{1,\}$//' file
```

Will remove an underscore, following by one or more digits from the end of each line. Note that the `_` doesn't require its own character class `[_]`. This is POSIX compliant, so should work regardless of your version of sed. It should also work equally well if the input is piped into sed.

The problem with using `[0-9]*` in your question is that is means **zero** or more, so **any** underscore will match the full expression and be removed.

---

It looks like your version of sed is pretty old! Rather than using the POSIX character class `[:digit:]`, you may have more success with `[0-9]`:

```
sed -e 's/_[0-9]\{1,\}//'
```

I have also removed the anchor to the end of the line `$`, in case that was causing any problems.

Comment: That latter version gives the desired result (exactly the same as the Borodin's perl command). Thanks for your contribution and the info about the SED version being quite old! I'll keep that in mind in future.

Answer (score 0):

`sed 's/_[0-9][0-9]*$//'` should do the trick

The output is:

```
    Sys!CTP_Live83000_@DRS_named_error_out
    EServerJTP!CTP_Live56000_@input_error_queue
```

The trick is using the dollar sign to force it to find the end of line.

Answer (score 0):

You can have:

```
sed 's/_[0-9]\+$//'
```

Which would match an underscore `_` and a number (one or more (`+`) digits `[0-9]`) at the end of the line or pattern (`$`).

Of course you can also use a character list:

```
sed 's/_[[:digit:]]\+$//'
```

With `-r` enabled, `+` is not needed to be quoted:

```
sed -r 's/_[0-9]+$//'
sed -r 's/_[[:digit:]]+$//'
```

You can also optionally add an extra pattern that would catch extra trailing spaces:

```
sed -r 's/_[0-9]+[ \t\r]*$//'
```